# If $\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{x_n}$ exists, can we conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Let the exponential function be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in  $\mathbb{R}.$ If $\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{x_n}$ exists, can we conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists? Appreciate all advice, thank you.

Comment: log is continuous. What do you know about continuous functions and limit of sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others pointed out, $\ln x $ is continuous on $\Bbb R^+$ giving you the answer for $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{x_n}>0$.

However, we have to be careful for $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{x_n}=0$. In this case we can only conclude that $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is divergent to $-\infty$ and thus the sequence does not converge. Take $x_n = -n$ for example.